# Javascript Drop Down

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a form that has multiple drop downs which get checked whether the user has selected something or not. Most fields are mandatory so upon clicking submit, red text replaces the black, showing which have to be filled in. It isn't validating for some reason or doing what it is i'm trying to accomplish. Other fields that have a id such as 'literature' work fine but this doesn't. Could it be because it's numeric?

Javascript:

```
var lit = document.getElementById("012");
var hasLeadLiterature = false;
for (j = 0;) {
    if (lit[j].selected === true) {
        hasLeadLiterature = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!hasLeadLiterature){
    changeCSS("lbl_literature", "errored");
    ErrorText=ErrorText+"11";
}
------
if (submitcount != 0){
    alert("This form has already been submitted.  Thank you!");
    return;
}

/** Submit form check */
if (ErrorText == ""){
    submitcount++; form.submit();
} else{
    return;
}
------
```

HTML:

```
<TR>
        <TD width="30%" valign="middle" ALIGN="left"><LABEL id="lbl_literature" for="lbl_literature" class="normal">How would you prefer to receive<br /> literature?: <SPAN class="required">*</SPAN></LABEL></TD><TD width="70%" valign="top" ALIGN="LEFT">
            <TABLE>
                    <TR>
                        <td class="text_input"> <!-- 012 -->

                            <select id="012" name="012" title="Literature Preference">
                                <option value="None">--None--</option>
                                <option value="Print">Print</option>
                                <option value="Digital">Digital</option>
                            </select>


                        </td>
                    </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </TD>
    </TR>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Any help with what?  You've described what you're doing, but you haven't asked a question or described any kind of problem?

Comment: It's not validating or showing the red text. Other fields work because I use id's such as 'industry' rather than numeric ones.

Comment: are you using any validation plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a **problem with your for loop**, it is not looping anything, have you checked it does loop?
I suggest you read up about how to use a for loop, correct code will be more like:
`for (var i=0; i<lit.length; i++)`
Because this loop is not valid `hasLeadLiterature` never changes which by the nature of your code bypasses everything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your validation is checking the opposite condition.  Take a look:

```
for (j = 0;) {
    if (lit[j].selected === true) {
        hasLeadLiterature = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you get rid of the unnecessary loop structure, you're doing this:

```
if (lit[0].selected === true) {
    hasLeadLiterature = true;
}
```

In this case, `lit[0]` is the first, empty `option` element in the `select` element.  So your condition is saying that if the empty option is selected, the form validates.  Shouldn't you reverse that condition?  Something like this:

```
if (lit[0].selected === false) {
    hasLeadLiterature = true;
}
```